# How do I remove ajaxpro *.ashx handlers from individual pages?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, httphandler, ajaxpro

I working on a ASP.NET web project where Ajaxpro.2 is referenced, and it seems automatically to add a bunch of ashx handlers to the page output - ie, core.ashx, prototype.ashx.

The problem is, I only need these to be present on a few pages, not the entire site. In trying to optimize the page download size (particularly for static public pages), it would be really good if I could stop these handlers being magically included everywhere. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the AjaxPro.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax only on the pages you want to have it, maybe a simple "if" statement would help.

Michael